# Difficulties in compiling the steady state of a biological model

Tags: equation-solving, modeling, systems-biology

I am modeling the yellow fever for an EDO system, in which I have to find the stationary states of the system, and I have great difficulty in finding something that can be very simple. I put the program to run and it keeps running forever. I thought it was the model, so I compiled another model in which I had already obtained the stationary states quickly, and the same one had the same problem. I tested on two other machines and the problem persists, including for the model I had compiled before and had got the points. I suppose it is error writing the system in wolfram to get the points of equilibrium, but the point is that this writing format I had already used to ober stationary states of the ODE in wolfram. What is wrong with calling the equations? Please tell me if you need the written template to try to help and excuse me for the English and if it is a trivial question, try to relieve me because I am new to the software.

```
Solve[-a*S[t]*P[t] + b*R[t] - c*S[t] + d*(S[t] + I1[t] + R[t]) == 0 &&
 a*S[t]*P[t] - e*I1[t] - (I1[t]*(c + P[t])) == 0 && e*I1 - b*R[t] == 
 0 && -f*N1[t]*I1[t] + g*(N1[t] + P[t])*(1 - (N1[t] + P[t])/k) - 
 h*N1[t] - c*N1[t] == 0 && 
 f*N1[t]*I1[t] - h*P[t] - c*P[t] == 0, {S[t], I1[t], R[t], N1[t], 
 P[t]}, t]
```

Comment: Replace && with commas and put  equations in { eqs }. There are no variables with  primes(derivations) in the equations..

Comment: Please edit both this post and the one you made on Wolfram Community, and cross link them (include a link to the other in each)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the platform, so I can not connect the links.

Answer (score 2):

**Comment**

Maple gives multiple solutions,

```
restart:
Eq1 := -a*S[t]*P[t] + b*R[t] - c*S[t] + d*(S[t] + I1[t] + R[t]) = 0;
Eq2 := a*S[t]*P[t] - e*I1[t] - (I1[t]*(c + P[t])) = 0;
Eq3 := e*I1 - b*R[t] = 0;
Eq4 := -f*N1[t]*I1[t] + g*(N1[t] + P[t])*(1 - (N1[t] + P[t])/k) - 
   h*N1[t] - c*N1[t] = 0;
Eq5 := f*N1[t]*I1[t] - h*P[t] - c*P[t] = 0;

solve({Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, Eq4, Eq5}, {S[t], I1[t], R[t], N1[t], P[t]})
```

Among which the less lengthy are

```
{I1[t]=0,N1[t]=-(k (c-g+h))/g,P[t]=0,R[t]=(e I1)/b,S[t]=(e I1 (b+d))/(b (c-d))},

{I1[t] = 0, N1[t] = 0, P[t] = 0, R[t] = e*I1/b, S[t] = e*I1*(b+d)/(b*(c-d))}
```

If I am not mistaken in `Eq3` there is `e*I1[t]` not `e*I1`?

If that is the case then some of the solutions are,

```
{I1[t] = 0, N1[t] = 0, P[t] = 0, R[t] = 0, S[t] = 0},
{I1[t] = 0, N1[t] = -k*(c-g+h)/g, P[t] = 0, R[t] = 0, S[t] = 0}
```

`Mathematica` is taking very long to produce any solution. Maybe we need to specify the different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
Solve[{
  -a*S*P + b*R - c*S + d*(S + I1 + R) == 0,
  a*S*P - e*I1 - (I1*(c + P)) == 0,
  e*I1 - b*R == 0,
  -f*N1*I1 + g*(N1 + P)*(1 - (N1 + P)/k) - h*N1 - c*N1 == 0,
  f*N1*I1 - h*P - c*P == 0}, {S, I1, R, N1, P}]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to return an answer (at least in a reasonable time) -- also with [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html).

You've got 5 nonlinear equations and 5 unknowns -- it is quite likely that there is no closed form analytical solution for all the equilibria.  The simpler ones that @zhk found with Maple seem to correspond to some populations extinct.

If you could write the original differential equations and give an interpretation, we might be able to see if there's a typo in your [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html).

Alternatively, you might need to use [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html).

Comment: I'm calculated by hand. I will open another post with questions regarding this. For I have taken the smaller equations and isolated some variables and biologically the results are right. But I need to confirm that my results are correct. In this case I found three variables and I will substitute in the equation that I want to isolate a certain variable. Therefore, I specify the values before and then place the equation in order to obtain a final solution. Only I can not isolate the variable I want. For him to give me the correct result